# Kohana Support For One Relationship Alias -> Multiple Models

Tags: orm, kohana, kohana-3

I was wondering if there is a way for Kohana to support something like this:

1. I have a model called Shopping List with an item_id
2. This item_id can reference objects from the following models: Beverage, Toy etc.

So if I do something like this:

```
protected $_has_one = array(
    'item' => array(
        'model' => 'beverage'
    )
);
```

how can I modify it to support one alias for multiple models?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And how to know what entity the current row refers to?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a table called Items which contains all your beverages, toys, etc and just has a category for them instead of completely separate tables?

If you do that, you can use ORM since it shows a relational mapping clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You should have Item model and table for it so that item_id will refer to this Item model. And then this model can have something like "type" property wich will explain what type of item this is (beverage or toy or anysyng else).